# Sound suddenly turns off

Tags: sound

I am using ubuntu 12.10.

Earlier sound used to randomly turn off when I closed my laptop's lid and laptop went to sleep, after waking it up there used to be no sound. I would then restart laptop to get the sound back.

Right now, I was watching a movie on VLC and sound suddenly muted. I restarted and have no sound yet. Any way to get it back on? and is there any permanent solution to this?

I researched other similar questions on askubuntu nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

While the VLC is playing check on the Ubuntu sound properties in the application tab if the VLC volume it is deactivate from there or if it is in the lowest level.